# "The type java.sql.Connection is not accessible" Eclipse IDE Error

Tags: java, import, package, mysql-connector

I searched stack overflow for similar errors, but didn't find quite the same.
I use the actual OpenJDK and imported the actual MySQL J connector.

If I try to import any `java.sql.*` package, it gets a red underline and won't do it.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 12):

Deleted `module-info.java`. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is just to add `requires java.sql;` to `module-info.java`. That way any other build dependencies are included as well.